# Desktop.open() silently fails on some JREs

Tags: java, desktop

I'm trying to use [`Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class to open a local HTML file on Windows. But it works only for some specific JREs, and not with some other JREs. 
Here is my code:

```
try {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)) {
            desktop.open(new File("test.html"));
        } else {
            throw new Exception("OPEN action not supported");
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Desktop not supported");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When it doesn't work, no Exception is thrown, and no text is printed in STDERR.

It works with:

- JRE 1.6.0_14 (32 bits)
- JRE 1.7.0_05 (32 bits)
- JRE 1.7.0_45 (64 bits)
- JRE 1.7.0_51 (64 bits)

It **does not** work with:

- JRE 1.6.0_26 (64 bits)
- JRE 1.6.0_37 (64 bits)
- JRE 1.7.0_02 (64 bits)
- JRE 1.7.0_21 (64 bits)   **EDIT : But works on CentOS**

All tests were performed on the same Win7 64 bits box.

*EDIT : Same issue when trying to open a "txt" or "pdf" file*

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Can you paste StackTrace ?
2. Cross-platform or only Winzoz ?

Comment: As I said, the problem is that I didn't catch any Exception... For the OS, I will test it on Linux

Comment: Is not supported on Linux without 3th p. API
Delete 'else throw new Exception ' and paste StackTrace.

Comment: Works great on Linux CentOS with JRE 1.7.0_51 (64 bits), will test it later with a JRE that doesn't work on Win7... What's the point in deleting 'else throw...' I don't see how it can produce more Exception?

Comment: You don't need a custom Exception (clear, without information) if you have a standard (implemented) Exception from class that you are using.

Comment: @O_T: ok got it. I removed this and nothing changed, I agree with your explanation but I just used these two "else" to detect unsupported operations for debugging :)

Comment: and with other file formats, like *.pdf or *.txt ?

Comment: look this [duplicate ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792298/facing-problems-with-java-awt-desktop-in-64-bit-jvm)

Comment: You do not seem to be the first with problems like this: http://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/java-awt-desktop-open-fails-silently-without-exception/ (see also related links there) and https://community.oracle.com/message/5487426 and http://www.techtalkz.com/java/126948-desktop-open-not-working-no-exceptions-errors.html (from 2007). It seems to be Windows related, and some report some connection with user account groups / settings. It's odd that reports are so scattered and information is vague.

Comment: Same issue for txt/pdf. And works on Linux with a JRE that failed on Windows (question updated). Thank you all. Guess I'm not gonna have a solution soon :/ ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with Java 1.6 and Desktop.open()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84460/problem-with-java-1-6-and-desktop-open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *"Stijn de Witt"* said in the comments of *"haventchecked"*'s answer, the solution based on `Runtime.getRuntime()` doesn't work with UNC paths, and with paths containing consecutive spaces. Here is the solution that also works with these special paths:

```
new ProcessBuilder("rundll32", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler", path).start();
```

Answer (score 5):

This problem has been around for a while now and has been documented with a few solutions [at this blog.](http://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/java-awt-desktop-open-fails-silently-without-exception/)

I've resorted to using the code below and it has been reliable on every Windows machine I've used regardless of JRE.  I'm sorry but I don't know all of the JREs I've tested with.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + path);
```

Comment: +1 Oops, I completely glossed over the workaround when I posted that link.

Comment: I'm actually the first reply on that thread so I've been following this with email notifications ever since.  I saw this question pop up coincidentally and had to chime in.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try on different Windows versions, but it seems a bit 'low level' to me (Windows 8 and next will also support this?). I'd have preferred letting the Java platform handles compatibility stuff for me...

Comment: OK. Works (for me) from XP SP3 to Windows 8.1, accepted this answer. It's a shame for Java to have this bug for all those years though.

Comment: I'm the author of that blog :)  Please, if you figure anything out about this issue, hop on over and add your findings. I wrote that post out of frustration with the Oracle forum admins closing all the threads related to the issue so there was never time to build a dossier on it. I'm trying to gather all info in one place.

Comment: About your solution. It works, but has it's own pitfalls. Especially test with: UNC paths, paths with spaces, path with two or more consecutive spaces. At work we tried to resort to this solution because of exactly the problem I blogged about, but the code ended up being VERY messy, because of specific issues with paths like the ones I mentioned. In the end we went back to desktop.open and now include a toggle that will switch to Runtime.exec as a fallback for those users where Desktop.open does not work.

Comment: @StijndeWitt I've just posted a new answer for this question, that solves the case of UNC and multiple-spaces paths :)

Comment: If using this approach, I suggest you wrap the path with quotes like so ...


    `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler '" + path + "'");`