# Open a pdf file with Desktop.open running eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

In windows environment, when I try

```
DesktopgetDesktop().open(file.pdf)
```

running a java application in eclipse 32bit, it successfully opens Acrobat Reader. If I do the same using eclipse 64bit, it does nothing, I just see Acrobat Reader in running processes but no windows will open ever. While if I open the file with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler pdffile"),
```

it open the file successfully in both environments.

I realized that Acrobat Reader is a 32bit application, so I suspected that the above behaviour depends on the jvm version, but the application started standalone with a 32bit or 64bit jvm, will run successfully. So I'm wondering that the problem is eclipse related, also because I observed the same behavior try opening a pdf file with eclipse openWith/System Editor menu option.
Is there something to do in eclipse configuration to avoid the above problem?

Comment: This is not related to Eclipse but to the JRE used, see e. g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/22418302/6505250

Comment: @howlger none of that jre are involved. Then launching the application outside eclipse, with the same jvm of eclipse environment, Acrobat Reader is opened successfully via Desktop.open.